# Set index based on same value python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

In python dataframe, I have a data frame like this

| index | column A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | c |
| 5 | c |
| 6 | c |

I want to create a column that will set index based on the same column's value

| index | column A | setIndex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 0 |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | b | 0 |
| 3 | c | 0 |
| 4 | c | 1 |
| 5 | c | 2 |
| 6 | c | 3 |

Comment: `df['setIndex'] = df.groupby('column A').cumcount()`

Comment: Use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), as follows:

```
df['setIndex'] = df.groupby('column A').cumcount()
```

**Result**:

```
print(df)

  column A  setIndex
0        a         0
1        a         1
2        b         0
3        c         0
4        c         1
5        c         2
6        c         3
```